# How to use DFT to find harmonic content of an AC waveform?

Tags: arm, fourier, fft, harmonics

I am kind of new to this coding and simulation environment. For my first project I need to take samples of current signals from power line and find out the harmonic contents using DFT. I haven't done anything like this before. From my coursework I know the equation for calculating DFT of the input sequence, but I am confused whether it is the same technique used while coding in C. I have to implement this project in an ARM processor and in C language. Please help me out. Let me know from where I can learn the basics and how to implement it. I little coding experience in C and used CCS to implement some simple projects in C2000 microcontroller launchpads but nothing like this sort.

Comment: If you look at Step 2 in my dft example [here](http://relayman.org/MCAD/dft.htm) you should be able to see how it’s done.  When I am back to my computer this afternoon I can improve this comment.

Comment: Yes it's the same equation (but FFT is usually faster). You'll easily find DFT or FFT software libraries, some of them are in C, so you won't need to code it yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by "harmonic content"??  Do you need the DFT, or something else, like total harmonic distortion?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ScottSeidman  By harmonic content I meant I need to extract the frequency values that is there in the input signal. And after that I need to analyze the harmonic content using some algorithm for identifying some indexes.

Comment: @user_1818839  Can you give some example or something? I need to implement it in ARM cortex M4 controller which is available in CC3220SF launchpad provided by TI. Is it possible to implement DFT or FFT in this controller? Or Should go for another microcontroller for the computation purpose?

Comment: google "open source DFT in C" and https://www.fftw.org/ is on the first page. I said it was easy